# Expire or Time Out never ending loop after X seconds

Tags: javascript

How can I stop this process after, say, 5 seconds?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeBanner(){ 
        // my change banner code
    }
    window.onload = function () { setInterval(changeBanner, 100) };
</script>
```

So currently I am changing the banner every 100 milliseconds. But I'd like it to stop after about 5 seconds.

I thought setTimeout might do the trick;

```
window.onload = function () { setTimeout(setInterval(changeBanner, 100), 5000) };
```

But that makes no difference.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the quick responses everyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'd like it to stop after about 5 seconds.

store the return value given by `setInterval` and use it with `clearInterval`

```
var timer = setInterval(changeBanner, 100);
setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(timer)
}, 5000);
```

There are also several libraries that implement function wrappers to achieve the same. For example, in [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#) you could use `_.before`:

```
var changeBannerLimited = _.before(50, changeBanner);
var timer = setInterval(changeBannerLimited, 100);
```

Note that contrary to using `clearInterval` this will continue to call the changeBannerLimited function forever, however after being called 50 times (10 * 5 seconds) it will no longer pass the call on to changeBanner.

*On a side note* I chose underscore.js because I know it well and because it provides nicely formated [annotated source code](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-88) so you can easily understand what's really going on behind the scenes.

Comment: I'm not a front-end developer and this is just a prototype application really. So I will probably use the clearInterval answer, thanks. I've never even heard of underscore.js but will bear it in mind if I start doing more front-end!

Answer (score 3):

You could store the return value of `setInterval` to a variable so that you can later cancel it:

```
function changeBanner(){ 
    // my change banner code
}
window.onload = function () {
    var id=setInterval(changeBanner, 100);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        window.clearInterval(id);
    },5000);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Use clearInterval.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var bannerInterval = setInterval(changeBanner, 100);
    setTimeout(function() {
        clearInterval(bannerInterval);
    }, 5000);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

persist  `setInterval` output  in variable  to be able to call `clearInterval`;

```
 window.onload = function () {

  var job= setInterval(changeBanner, 100) ;
  setTimeout(clearInterval(job), 5000)

};
```